# Batch shift folder name

Tags: batch-file

I need make a batch to found and get some words form its folder name(temp-yy-mm-dd), e.g. `temp-19-01-01`, then need result 19-01-01 for another use!

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`dir temp-**-**-** /b /s /a:d `) do (
  echo %%i
  )
endlocal
```

The result is `c:\temp\temp-19-01-01`

But I only need `19-01-01` to %%j

Please help with thanks!

Answer (score 0):

parse your result a second time (delimit by `-` and `tokens=1,*`, where `*` means "take all the rest and don't tokenize any more":

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`dir temp-??-??-?? /b /s /a:d `) do (
  echo %%i
  for /f "tokens=1,* delims=-" %%a in ("%%~ni") do echo %%b
  )
endlocal
```

The wildcard `*` means "any number of characters", but you want a known number, so you have to use `?`, which means "exactly one character"

Comment: Thanks for advice! After I get the result(folder name > temp-19-01-01), I need 19-01-01 which is the date, I need compare with today's date then echo Old Data Folder if the 19-01-01 is older than 100 days!

Comment: `%%b` is exactly the string you neeed. If you need it in a variable, replace `echo %%b` with `set "var=%%b".

Comment: for the "older than 100 days", take a look at the [forfiles](https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) command, especially the `/D - dd` part.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different implementation to include a [findstr](/questions/tagged/findstr) check for a better directory name match pattern.

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B /S /A:D "temp-??-??-??" 2^> NUL ^|^
 FindStr /I /R "\\temp-[0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]$"'
) Do For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=-" %%B In ("%%~nxA") Do Echo(%%C
Pause
```

Comment: yes, of course `?`, not `*`. My brain needs more caffeine... "borrowed" that for my answer `:)`

Comment: Thanks advice again! The folder "temp-19-01-01" is the folder create date. I need get the value "19-01-01" to compare with today. If the value older than 180 days, return old data otherwise return normal data. e.g. Today is 2019-06-01, then for folder named "temp-19-01-01 > output is normal data, for folder named "temp-18-11-01 > output old data!

Comment: You can compare instead of `Echo(%%C`. Your question was answered, we're not modifying our answers to incorporate your new question. If you're not sure how to perform that part of the task, try searching the site. Please remember, before you do, that if you're wanting to use date strings, that you should be aware that the strings as they appear as `%DATE%` are not objects, and can be different on everyone's PC. You would therefore need to find a method which is not locale/PC dependent.